# Laptop audio issues using boxes

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, drivers

I'm having a problem with my boxes. I have a sub woofer, which is connected with 4 boxes. The sub woofer is connected with the laptop. It used to work fine, beautiful sound through all the boxes. However, since yesterday it was acting weird.

Yesterday it played the sound through only 1 box and through the laptop. So i checked my settings, it was on stereo (I don't know if it was on stereo when it was still working) and the L was playing through 1 L box and the R was playing through the laptop.

Today I tried to fix it, I tried updating my drivers (I have Realtek Semiconductor Corp.) I downloaded the latest version for windows 7 (6.0.1.6839), which should be compatible with my hardware (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0269&SUBSYS_10250647&REV_1001). But it wasn't fixed. When I now plug in the boxes, it plays L through my 2 left boxes and R isn't playing at all.

So I hoped updating the drivers would fix it, but it didn't. I also tried rollback drivers, but it also doesn't fix it.

When i plug in headphones, the headphones work fine.

Does any have any ideas on how to fix this?
I really love music, and playing through my laptop just isn't satisfying enough :(.

Many thanks in advance!

P.S. I also checked if anything was plugged in correctly, and it was.

Comment: The important question here is; are they satin or cotton?

Comment: How can I check? Or are you trolling?

Comment: All jokes aside. How does the speaker system split the signal out to the 4 speakers + subwoofer?

Comment: Like this: http://s12.postimg.org/fpyrkbing/foto.jpg
The green one, the 'FRONT' is connected with the laptop.

Comment: Also, I just noticed this: http://s21.postimg.org/54zp9ddd3/foto2.png
I believe one of those jack 'circles' used to be green surrounded, which they are not now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a problem with the jack cable. Try to half-plug your headphones and you should get a similar behavior.

Could also be a problem with the "Right front" cable since it seems to combine different cables (line in and out). Those type of connector are a bit weak and can lead to a faulty contact. While playing music try to disconnect-reconnect it or move it while it's plugged, if your hear some crackling or music starts playing in another speaker, then it probably comes from here. I already fixed 2 of those by cutting them and soldering them directly on the PCB.

Check if your connectors aren't oxidized or dirty too.